# Convolution with separable kernel

Tags: c++, math, cuda, convolution

I'm looking at the [CUDA SDK convolution with separable kernels](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/), and I have a simple question but can't find an answer:

Do the vectors, whose convolution gives the kernel, need to have the same size? Can I first perform a row-convolution with a vector 1x3 and then a column convolution with another one 5x1 ? Or they both need to be same size? Google isn't helping (or I'm unable to search for an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the vectors can be different sizes.  The only consequence is that you'll get a rectangular matrix that is not square.

Comment: This is only if you do a full convolution. You could limit the output to be the same size as the input. Depends on the application you are using the convolution for.

Answer (score 3):

The vectors of a separable convolution could only be different sizes if the equivalent convolution matrix was not square.